# Последовательный вывод текста путем echo PHP в браузер не ожадая полной отработки скрипта

Tags: вывод, php, echo

Надо выводить последовательно текст через echo по ходу выполнения скрипта, но все `echo` выводятся только когда скрипт полностью отработан. Пробовал отключать `output_buffering 0`, включать `implicit_flush`, ставить после `echo` функцию `flush()`, эффекта не дало..
Есть ли какая-нибудь настройка, которая может сделать желаемый результат? Подскажите, пожалуйста, кто знает..

связка `OpenSUSE 12.3 + PHP 5.3.19 + Apache2`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Да есть, надо в `.htaccess` в директории с приложением прописать

```
php_value output_buffering Off
php_value zlib.output_compression Off
```

Ну и `flush()` делать.

Не забыть сделать `AllowOverride` в настройках `vhost`

Comment: Да, большое спасибо так работает. Примечательно, что без flush() не хотит

Comment: flush() это чтобы указать место, где надо сбросить буфер.